# Is there an overhead in my code that makes my threading slower [C++]

Tags: performance, c++, multithreading

I have created two programs that find the determinant of 2 matrixes, with one using threads and the other without and then recorded the time taken to complete the calculation. The threaded script appears to be slower than the one without threads yet I cannot see anything that may create any overhead issues. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Thread script:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <thread>

void determinant(int matrix[3][3]){
  int a = matrix[0][0]*((matrix[1][1]*matrix[2][2])-(matrix[1][2]*matrix[2][1]));
  int b = matrix[0][1]*((matrix[1][0]*matrix[2][2])-(matrix[1][2]*matrix[2][0]));
  int c = matrix[0][2]*((matrix[1][0]*matrix[2][1])-(matrix[1][1]*matrix[2][0]));
  int determinant = a-b+c;
}

int main() {
  int matrix[3][3]= {
    {11453, 14515, 1399954}, 
    {13152, 11254, 11523}, 
    {11539994, 51821, 19515}
  };
  int matrix2[3][3] = {
    {16392, 16999942, 18682}, 
    {5669, 466999832, 1429}, 
    {96989, 10962, 63413}
  };
  const clock_t c_start = clock();
  std::thread mat_thread1(determinant, matrix);
  std::thread mat_thread2(determinant, matrix2);
  mat_thread1.join();
  mat_thread2.join();
  const clock_t c_end = clock();
  std::cout << "\nOperation takes: " << 1000.0 * (c_end-c_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "ms of CPU time";
}
```

Script with no other thread than the main one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <thread>

void determinant(int matrix[3][3]){
  int a = matrix[0][0]*((matrix[1][1]*matrix[2][2])-(matrix[1][2]*matrix[2][1]));
  int b = matrix[0][1]*((matrix[1][0]*matrix[2][2])-(matrix[1][2]*matrix[2][0]));
  int c = matrix[0][2]*((matrix[1][0]*matrix[2][1])-(matrix[1][1]*matrix[2][0]));
  int determinant = a-b+c;
}

int main() {
  int matrix[3][3]= {
    {11453, 14515, 1399954}, 
    {13152, 11254, 11523}, 
    {11539994, 51821, 19515}
  };
  int matrix2[3][3] = {
    {16392, 16999942, 18682}, 
    {5669, 466999832, 1429}, 
    {96989, 10962, 63413}
  };
  const clock_t c_start = clock();
  determinant(matrix);
  determinant(matrix2);
  const clock_t c_end = clock();
  std::cout << "\nOperation takes: " << 1000.0 * (c_end-c_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "ms of CPU time";
}
```

PS - the 1st script took 0.293ms on the last run and the second script took 0.002ms

Thanks again,

wndlbh

Comment: This appears to be a question about programming. Not a question about Unix.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the issue lied within the code or within the actual hardware (ie - using taskset to force the script onto a certain cpu, making the code work as expected).

Answer (score 5):

The difference seems to be the **creation** of two threads and the **joins**. I expect that the time to do this (create and join) is way more than the time to do 9 multiplications and 5 additions.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't the threads run concurrently though?

Comment: ***Shouldn't the threads run concurrently though?*** Yes but it takes more time to create the threads than it does to do the work so a single threaded code will be faster. You will have to test your code with a much larger matrix to see the multithreaded code win.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will have to try this and see the difference in action

Answer (score 0):

The start-up (and tear down) cost of a new thread is enormous, and in this case drowns the real work.
I seem to remember times between 1ms and 1s depending on your setup. More threads first helps if the time saved on the work is higher than the cost of creating the threads. In this case you would need 1000's of calculations to save that much.